# Como agregar un nodo nieto a un treeview (archivo .txt)

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema al generar un nodo nieto (ya un tercer nodo) de un **archivo** txt el cual posee esto:

```
Cordoba*Villa Maria*Barrio Lamadrid
Cordoba*Villa Maria*Barrio Ameghino
Cordoba*Villa Maria*Barrio Centro
Cordoba*Villa Maria*Barrio Palermo
Cordoba*Villa Nueva*Barrio La Reserva
```

Aca esta el código que use

```
 foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // Separa el contenido de la línea por el caracter *
            var parts = line.Split('*');
            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                // Si no está creado el nodo con la primera parte lo                   añade
                if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(parts[0], parts[0]);
                }
                // Seleccionamos el nodo padre con la primera parte
                var firstLevel = treeView1.Nodes[parts[0]];
                // Si no existe un nodo con la segunda parte, lo crea
                if (!firstLevel.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[1]))
                {
                    firstLevel.Nodes.Add(parts[1], parts[1]);
                }

            }
            else if (parts.Length == 3)
            {
                // Si no está creado el nodo con la primera parte lo   añade
                if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(parts[0], parts[0]);
                }
                // Seleccionamos el nodo padre con la primera parte
                var firstLevel = treeView1.Nodes[parts[0]];
                // Si no existe un nodo con la segunda parte, lo crea
                if (!firstLevel.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[1]))
                {
                    firstLevel.Nodes.Add(parts[1], parts[1]);
                }
                // Seleccionamos el nodo padre con la segunda parte
                var secondLevel = treeView1.Nodes[parts[1]];
                // Si no existe un nodo con la tercera parte, lo crea
                if (!secondLevel.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[2])) ERROR  "referencia  a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"
                {
                    secondLevel.Nodes.Add(parts[2], parts[2]);
                }
            }

        }
```

Querria saber como seria el codigo a partir del `ELSE IF`, ya que me tira un **error:**

> "referencia  a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto".

Comment: Puedes indicar el mensaje de error? En que línea en concreto te da. Te funciona solo con padre y el hijo ? Cordoba*Villa Maria . Podrías ver que valores tiene parts o si secondLevel es null

Comment: Señale el error en la linea con comillas, second level me da null.